# Area bounded by polar function

Tags: calculus, area

> Calculate the area bounded by $r = \cos(4\theta)$.

[image]

Since the formula for calculating area is $\int_a^b (1/2)r^2d\theta$, where a and b are the theta values for the sector, I tried:

$$8\int_0^{\pi/4} (1/2)*{\cos(4\theta)}^2d\theta$$

because the integral finds the area of 1 petal (50% of a petal + 50% of another petal) and we multiply in by 8 to get the full area. This yields an area of about 1.571. I also tried $4\int_0^{\pi/2} (1/2)*{\cos(4\theta)}^2d\theta$ and got 1.571.

However, the answer key says
$$\int_{0}^{\pi/3} {\cos^2(\theta)-(1/4)}d\theta$$

This is about 0.478.

Where did I go wrong?

---

**EDIT:** Sorry, my answer (1.571) was correct. I just read the wrong answer from the answer key.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To find the area of one petal, figure our where the function is $0$ and goes to zero again, integrate over that area and that's the area of one petal. Or, by symmetry, find half the area of one petal, multiply is by two to get the area of one full petal, then mutliply by $8$ to get the area of all $8$ petals. At $\theta=0$, $r=1$. Then, when does $r=0$ after that? Well, we want to then solve $0=\cos(4\theta)\implies 4\theta=\frac{\pi}{2},\frac{3\pi}{2},\frac{5\pi}{2},\ldots\implies \theta=\frac{\pi}{8},\frac{3\pi}{8},\frac{5\pi}{8},\ldots$. So, $\frac{\pi}{8}$ is our second theta. So, the are of all $8$ loops is $$8\cdot 2\cdot\int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{8}}\frac{1}{2}\cos^2(4\theta)d\theta=\ldots=\frac{\pi}{2}$$
Yours is right. Perhaps their answer key is wrong or you're reading the wrong one? It seems they calculated the area between the curves $r=\cos(\theta)$ and $r=\frac{1}{2}$.

Comment: Sorry, yes I was reading the wrong answer. Thanks for your help!

Comment: It happens. No problem. Glad I could help.